# How to deletes files which are added to commit

Tags: git, post-commit

I have added two new files to my commit, and deleted them after commiting to my local repo , how can delete those files from the same commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you did the following:

```
//Created files A.txt and B.txt
git add A.txt
git add B.txt
git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Now you want that the previous commit didn't have the two files A.txt and B.txt, so you can do:

```
git rm A.txt
git rm B.txt
git commit --amend
```

But remember, if you **PUSHED** that commit, **DON'T AMEND**, instead, create a new commit that deletes the two files.

Comment: At least unless you aren't sure that nobody has pulled your changes yet.

Answer (score 1):

> git reset --soft HEAD^

This will undo your last commit and put your repo in the state right before you did the last commit. From here you can unstage and undo add/delete of files etc.